# How will moderators be chosen

Tags: discussion

Will moderators be chosen by the users? assigned based on reputation?  What is the best way to choose those who will have the final say in arguments, and insure the site stays on course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far what most metas have been doing, and approved by the SE team, is to hold nominations. About one week after public beta starts, the SE team will pick 3 from among the nominees to be moderators. Read This: [How to organize a formal moderator election on a beta SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site)

Also, if you want to see how it is being done on webapps and cooking, look here:

- https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/moderator-nominations
- https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations

Answer (score 0):

I expect we'll have a similar process to other beta SE sites, like on [Web Apps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations).  The StackExchangians will obviously have a lot of say, like [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations/276#276) to that question.